# Efficiently storing a set of numbers

Tags: c#, data-structures

I am looking for the most efficient way to store a collection of integers.  Right now they're being stored in a `HashSet<T>`, but profiling has shown that these collections weigh heavily on some performance-critical code and I suspect there's a better option.

Some more details:

- Random lookups must be O(1) or close to it.
- The collections can grow large, so space efficiency is desirable.
- The values are uniformly distributed in a 64-bit space.
- Mutability is not needed.
- There's no clear upper bound on size, but tens of millions of elements is not uncommon.

The most painful performance hit right now is creating them. That seems to be allocation-related - clearing and reusing `HashSet`s helps a lot in benchmarks, but unfortunately that is not a feasible option in the application code.

(added) Implementing a data structure that's tailored to the task is fine. Is a hash table still the way to go?  A trie also seems like a possibility at first glance, but I don't have any practical experience with them.

Comment: Is there an upper bound on the values that you plan to store? How large is "large"?

Comment: Where do you spend most of the time? Reading or writing to the collections?

Comment: What other data is associated with the integers? Is it literally just a pile of integers or is there other data hanging off? (in other words, what do you mean by "random lookups"?)

Comment: Edited to add responses to other questions. Lookup is merely checking to see whether a set contains a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to try and implement a special purpose hash-based set class that uses linear probing to handle collisions:

- Backing store is a simple array of `long`s
- The array is sized to be larger than the expected number of elements to be stored.
- For a value's hash code, use the least-significant 31 bits.

Searching for the position of a value in the backing store is done using a basic linear probe, like so:

```
int FindIndex(long value)
{
    var index = ((int)(value & 0x7FFFFFFF) % _storage.Length;
    var slotValue = _storage[index];

    if(slotValue == 0x0 || slotValue == value) return index;

    for(++index; ; index++)
    {
        if (index == _storage.Length) index = 0;
        slotValue = _storage[index];
        if(slotValue == 0x0 || slotValue == value) return index;
    }
}
```

(I was able to determine that the data being stored will never include 0, so that number is safe to use for empty slots.)

The array needs to be larger than the number of elements stored. (Load factor less than 1.) If the set is ever completely filled then `FindIndex()` will go into an infinite loop if it's used to search for a value that isn't already in the set.  In fact, it will want to have quite a lot of empty space, otherwise search and retrieval may suffer as the data starts to form large clumps.

I'm sure there's still room for optimization, and I will may get stuck using some sort of `BigArray<T>` or sharding for the backing store on large sets. But initial results are promising.  It performs over twice as fast as `HashSet<T>` at a load factor of 0.5, nearly twice as fast with a load factor of 0.8, and even at 0.9 it's still working 40% faster in my tests.

Overhead is `1 / load factor`, so if those performance figures hold out in the real world then I believe it will also be more memory-efficient than `HashSet<T>`.  I haven't done a formal analysis, but judging by the internal structure of `HashSet<T>` I'm pretty sure its overhead is well above 10%.

--

So I'm pretty happy with this solution, but I'm still curious if there are other possibilities.  Maybe some sort of trie?

--

**Epilogue:** Finally got around to doing some competitive benchmarks of this vs. `HashSet<T>` on live data. (Before I was using synthetic test sets.)  It's even beating my optimistic expectations from before.  Real-world performance is turning out to be as much as 6x faster than `HashSet<T>`, depending on collection size.

Answer (score 1):

`HashSet` is usually the best general purpose collection in this case.

If you have any specific information about your collection you may have better options.

If you have a fixed upper bound that is not incredibly large you can use a bit vector of suitable size.

If you have a very dense collection you can instead store the missing values.

If you have very small collections, <= 4 items or so, you can store them in a regular array. A full scan of such small array may be faster than the hashing required to use the hash-set.

If you don't have any more specific characteristics of your data than "large collections of `int`" `HashSet` is the way to go.

Comment: I fear it isn't. For example, `HashSet<T>` stores both a value and its hash code. In this case the data can be its own hash code, though, so doing that is an unnecessary usage of space. It makes the collections less compact, and also slower (redundant comparisons, less cache-friendly, &c).

Answer (score 1):

If the size of the values is bounded you could use a bitset. It stores one bit per integer. In total the memory use would be log n bits with n being the greatest integer.

Another option is a bloom filter. Bloom filters are very compact but you have to be prepared for an occasional false positive in lookups. You can find more about them in wikipedia.

A third option is using a simle sorted array. Lookups are log n with n being the number of integers. It may be fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is just create an array of integers with a sufficient enough size to handle how ever many integers you need.  Is there any reason from staying away from the generic `List<T>`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx

Comment: *"lookups must be O(1) or close to it"*

Answer (score 0):

> The most painful performance hit right now is creating them...

As you've obviously observed, `HashSet<T>` does not have a constructor that takes a `capacity` argument to initialize its capacity.

One trick which I believe would work is the following:

```
int capacity = ... some appropriate number;
int[] items = new int[capacity];
HashSet<int> hashSet = new HashSet<int>(items);
hashSet.Clear();
...
```

Looking at the implementation with reflector, this will initialize the capacity to the size of the `items` array, ignoring the fact that this array contains duplicates.  It will, however, only actually add one value (zero), so I'd assume that initializing and clearing should be reasonably efficient.

I haven't tested this so you'd have to benchmark it.  And be willing to take the risk of depending on an undocumented internal implementation detail.

It would be interesting to know why Microsoft didn't provide a constructor with a `capacity` argument like they do for other collection types.

Comment: Just tested it. Creating them using this method takes about 50% longer than starting from an empty `HashSet<long>`.